# Android code to Broadcast live audio stream from phone

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, rtsp

I am new to android, can anyone provide me the code to broadcast live audio from phone mike to media players like ffmpeg,vlc,etc... over the lan using wifi without using NDK?

[Edit]
So far i have implemented it using libstreaming library

https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

and is working fine except for one issue, only one player is able to receive it at a time(since it is unicast). i want to change it to be able to be received in more than one player at the same time.

My code snippet is:

```
 mSurfaceView = (net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

// Sets the port of the RTSP server to 1234
Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
editor.putString(RtspServer.KEY_PORT, String.valueOf(5060));                                                            // audio port num               
editor.commit();

// Configures the SessionBuilde
SessionBuilder.getInstance()
.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
.setPreviewOrientation(90)
.setContext(getApplicationContext())
.setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
.setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_NONE);


MainActivity.this.startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,RtspServer.class))
```

Comment: @BoskoMijin : now you can see the edited post,